# Regex parsing of filenames

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to use the `dropbox_uploader.sh` script to upload a bunch of images with the same name (`200.jpg`) but in different folders.

So I have `.../a/200.jpg`, `.../b/200.jpg`, etc and I would like them to upload to `Folder/a/200.jpg` and `Folder/b/200.jpg`. Currently, they are overriding each other as just "`200.jpg`"

This is what I have now that has resulted in the above: 
`../Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload */200.jpg Folder/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` to do this,

```sh
find */ -name '200.jpg' -exec dropbox_uploader.sh upload ./"{}" Folder/"{}" \;
```

This will find all files named 200.jpg within subdirectories of the current directory, and then call `dropbox_uploader.sh`. It ends up executing something like this:

```
dropbox_uploader.sh upload a/200.jpg Folder/a/200.jpg
dropbox_uploader.sh upload b/200.jpg Folder/b/200.jpg
```

If you need to make the directories before you can upload to them, then you can do something like this

```sh
find */ -name '200.jpg' -exec dirname "{}" \; | \
     xargs -I"{}" dropbox_uploader.sh mkdir Folder/"{}"
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw in the source code of dropbox_uploader.sh, the script doesn't support this behavior.

You should build a list of the files you need to upload in your script and then call dropbox_uploader.sh upload for each file in the list.

This way, you will have more control on which files to select and do more advanced filtering if needed.

Comment: I just need to extract the directory name of the image so that I can create the same directory on Dropbox